# how can I extract out pci codes from lspci

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

I need to extract out pci codes for my gpus. How can I do that?

when I run:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i nvidia
```

I get:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b06] (rev a1)
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
02:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10ef] (rev a1)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b06] (rev a1)
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
03:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10ef] (rev a1)
```

I'd like to extract out:

`02:00.0` and `02:00.1` and the other nvidia ids in order to feed into a subsequent script.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
lspci -nnk | awk '/NVIDIA/{print $1}'
```

that will print the first word of each line containing `NVIDIA`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i nvidia | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the PCI bus addresses, change the `grep` command to:

```
grep -Pio '^[.-:]*(?=.*nvidia)'
```

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution:

```
lspci -nnk | perl -anE '/nvidia/i && $F[0] =~ /^[0-9a-f:.]+$/i && say $F[0]'
```

- `-a` - split line on whitespace
- `-n` - loop over lines but don't print
- `-E <command>` - command to execute inside the loop
- `/nvidia/` - match lines containing `nvidia` (case insensitive)
- `$F[0] =~ /^[0-9a-f:.]+$/` - first column of the line (split by the `-a`) matches one or more of hexadecimal digit, colon and dot